# ASP.NET EnqityDataSource WhereParameters, creates new property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I am trying to populate GridView, using EntityDataSource(code behind), I need to able to sort GridView. However when I sort i get error:
 **A property with name 'aspnet_Users.UserId1' does not exist in metadata for entity type**
So I beleive it is because I generate where parameter in code behind:

```
ActiveEnqDataSource.WhereParameters.Add(new SessionParameter("aspnet_Users.UserId", TypeCode.Object, "UserName"));
```

Full code is :

```
ActiveEnqDataSource.ConnectionString = db.Connection.ConnectionString;
             ActiveEnqDataSource.DefaultContainerName = "Entities";
             ActiveEnqDataSource.EntitySetName = "Enquiries";
             ActiveEnqDataSource.Include = "UserCars.CarModel.CarMake, Category, aspnet_Users";

             ActiveEnqDataSource.EnableUpdate = true;
             ActiveEnqDataSource.EnableInsert = true;
             ActiveEnqDataSource.EnableDelete = true;
             ActiveEnqDataSource.AutoGenerateWhereClause = true;


             ActiveEnqDataSource.WhereParameters.Add(new SessionParameter("aspnet_Users.UserId", TypeCode.Object, "UserName"));
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much! The gridview itself renders perfectly, only thing I cannot sort it, any "whereParameters" I add, Add 1 to the property e.g UserId1,EnquiryStatus1, ProdauctName1. etc...

Comment: WhereParameters are for filtering, not for sorting, aren't they? Are you trying to sort the GridView with the LinkButtons in the GridViewHeader? If so, it would be helpful if you could provide a piece of your GridView markup. In the code you provided until now I can't see any sorting at all. Or do you mean you get this error as soon as you add the WhereParameter? Does it work without the Where filter by UserName?

Comment: Yes it does work perfectly without where clause wich is for filtering. The markup is standard, sorting enabled using control "tag".
Actually I have resolved it by puting where clause in the markup, not code-behind. It does work. However the question is still, open why it does not work from code behind :)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error because I was adding the where clause each time the page was posted back.  Dropping my code that generated the where clause inside an IsPostback statement fixed the problem:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    // code to add where parameters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used markup to define a Where parameter AND then I added the same parameter in code. Somewhere along the line, the 1 at the end of the parameter name was added.